# Paypal checkout express just add product to the cart?

Tags: magento-1.9, cart, paypal-express

I enabled paypal express, but it just add the product to the cart, so you need to click it again from the cart view. Should not redirect straightly to the paypal website skipping the cart? if yes, what is going wrong?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem, it was the 'ajax cart' plugin integrated into the template. I disabled it and now works fine

Comment: yes I know, I've to wait 1 day more